# shadowRoot.getSelection()?

Tags: shadow-dom, lit-element, lit

I have a rich editor I'm re-writing as a lit-element custom element.  I'm using Firefox (latest) for testing. I'm trying to get the selection for the content editable element in the custom element's shadowDom (in a method).

In the Firefox debugger), `this.shadowRoot` looks correct for the shadowRoot element, but `this.shadowRoot.getSelection` is not defined,
even though [DocumentOrShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot)
says `shadowRoot.getSelection()` is the proper way to get the selection within the shadow DOM.
Can anybody shed light on something I'm missing?

Many thanks!

Comment: Answering my own question: it looks like for working inside the shadowRoot, one should use shadowRoot.getSelection() on Chrome, and document.getSelection() on other browsers.

Comment: did document.getSelection() return nodes inside the shadow root on Safari & FF?

Comment: Justin, "document.getSelection()" works on FF; I haven't tried it on Safari, but I think I was told it did.

Comment: @JustinFagnani it does work in FF but it shows only container of shadow dom in Safari.

Answer (score 10):

The state of affairs as of Dec 2023:

`ShadowRoot.getSelection` [is a non-standard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot).

`Selection.getComposedRanges` is a [standards proposal to support selection with Shadow DOM](https://w3c.github.io/selection-api/#dom-selection-getcomposedrange).

On Chromium, calling `document.getSelection` will not pierce into the Shadow DOM and gives you some unhelpful high-level element. But it does expose the non-standard `getSelection` method on the ShadowRoot.

On Firefox, it does not implement `ShadowRoot.getSelection`, but `document.getSelection` will pierce through shadow dom and give you the exact element.

On Safari, `Selection.getComposedRanges` is supported as of v17. On versions before that, `ShadowRoot.getSelection` is not supported and apparently `document.getSelection` does *not* pierce the Shadow DOM, meaning you are just out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to get a Selection within shadowdom myself for days.
My understanding so far is that "this.shadowRoot.getSelection()" works fine
(tested in Chrome and Firefox),
but only for shadowdom in "open"-mode, because "this.shadowRoot" can't be accessed 
in "closed"-mode: "Cannot read property 'getSelection' of null".

Of course you can store a reference to shadowRoot yourself at initialization time,
however it is hard to keep this reference private in JavaScript.

Comment: When I tested in Firefox, `this.shadowRoot.getSelection` was undefined. The docs page has it listed as "non-standard": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot

Answer (score 2):

There's a proposal currently in development to extend the Selection API to properly handle Shadow DOM. See https://twitter.com/bocoup/status/1459120675390689284?s=20

Comment: there is no thread there: https://pasteboard.co/SuKLFLVF3h5D.png