# Get selection range of shadow DOM tree

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, getselection

If we have two nodes outer and inner, each one of them has shadowRoot

```js
      const inner = document.createElement("span");
      inner.attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).innerHTML = "inner";

      const outer = document.createElement("span");
      outer.attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).append("outer ", inner);

      document.body.append(outer);
```

[image]

Then we select a text exists in both

[image]

If we try to get selected text

```js
window.getSelection().toString()
```

We get `'er '` which is incorrect! Even if try to get selection on the shadowRoot of inner span it not correct.

- How to get selection is this case?

Comment: I'm surprised you can even make that selection as a user. Last time I tried that wasn't even possible to achieve for a user...

Comment: As per this discussion this is repeat question - you can read about it here 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523247/7255780